# SQL - Simplify UNION Query

Tags: sql, join, union

I am currently using the following query to join two tables together:

```
select distinct book_id, clean_page_content as page_content, 'clean' as status, reg_date
from book_db_clean_pages t
where book_id = 'sarafi_book_5'
and   reg_date = '2015-08-26'

UNION all

select distinct book_id, dirty_page_content as page_content, 'dirty' as status, reg_date
from book_db_dirty_pages e
where book_id = 'sarafi_book_5'
and   reg_date = '2015-08-26'
```

However, when I want look for a different **book_id** I need to change two clauses (one above and one below the **UNION**). The same principle applied to the **reg_date**. So I was wondering whether it was possible to simplify my query just using perhaps commands like **join** or other things. In principle, I am looking for a solution *like* this:

```
select distinct t.book_id, (t.clean_page_content or e.dirty_page_content) as page_content, 
       ('clean' or 'dirty') as status, t.reg_date
from book_db_clean_pages t, book_db_dirty_pages e
where t.book_id = e.book_id and t.reg_date = e.reg_date
and t.book_id = 'sarafi_book_5'
and t.reg_date = '2015-08-26'
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT when UNION, all duplicates are removed anyway.

Comment: What it you had a view and selected from that?

Answer (score 2):

Put your union into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
   select ...
   from book_db_clean_pages t
   -- no where clause 

   union all

   select ...
   from book_db_dirty_pages e
   where t.book_id = e.book_id and t.reg_date = e.reg_date
   -- no where clause for book_id and reg_date

) t
where book_id = 'sarafi_book_5'
and reg_date = '2015-08-26';
```

All modern DBMS will be smart enough to push the condition into the derived table, so there shouldn't be a performance loss when you do so.

---

Btw: if `book_id`  is the primary key (or a unique column) in the two tables, applying the `distinct` on the inner selects will not remove anything.

Comment: your btw part makes little sense to me. if `distinct` will not remove anything, `union ` will not either since the status column in each union part is different.

Comment: @Aツ: the union will remove duplicates in the _overall result_, e.g. when a book_id (assuming that _is_ the primary key) appears in both tables with the same attributes. That is something different than removing duplicates in each query result individually (which probably won't happen anyway if `book_id` is unique in those tables)

Comment: op defines the status differently in each part of the union. which makes sure that the rows are different.

Comment: @Aツ: yep, I just realized that ;) but still the `distinct` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify the query as you have written it.

You can write:

```
select distinct b.*
from ((select book_id, clean_page_content as page_content, 'clean' as status, reg_date
       from book_db_clean_pages t
      ) union all
      (select book_id, dirty_page_content as page_content, 'dirty' as status, reg_date
       from book_db_dirty_pages e
      )
     ) b
where book_id = 'sarafi_book_5' and reg_date = '2015-08-26';
```

You do not mention the database you are using.  Your initial query might be significantly more efficient, if the subqueries can make use of indexes.